# How to use a HELM-3 value a multi-line string

Tags: string, multiline, helm3

I'm having an nginx ConfigMap yaml file which is then mounted as nginx.conf. This config map contains the config in a multiline string starting like the following:

```
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    worker_processes  auto;
    pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
    :
```

and in this multiline string I'd like to inject a value from the values.yaml like for example:

```
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    worker_processes  auto;
    pid /tmp/nginx.pid;

:
:
        log_format combined '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                           '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                           '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log {{ .Values.nginx.log.format | default "combined" | quote }};
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
:
```

but using the syntax above I'm getting an unexpected EOF error. Any way/work-around to get this done?

Answer (score -1):

Well, I would suggest you to avoid doing this. Instead, you can create a folder such as `configuration`, sibling to your `template` folder and create a file named `nginx.conf` in it with your entire string content which of course can have required placeholders. Then, in configMap definition, you can call your file like this

```
data:
{{ (.Files.Glob "configuration/nginx.conf").AsConfig | indent 2 }}
```

This would create your configmap